# How to give hdfs path in Apache Tika using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
object newpdf {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","appName")
    val path = "hdfs://namenode2.aibl.net:8020/ABDF/akhilaajith/PF_knnmodel_1231480046927236/visualise1/model_points"
    val data = sc.binaryFiles(path)
    val rdd =    data.map(x => {
      tikaFunc(x)
    })
    rdd.foreach(println)
  }

  def tikaFunc(a: (String, PortableDataStream)) = {
    val file: File = new File(a._1.drop(5))
    val myparser: AutoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser()
    val stream: InputStream = new FileInputStream(a._1)
    val handler: WriteOutContentHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler(-1)
    val metadata: Metadata = new Metadata()
    val context: ParseContext = new ParseContext()
    myparser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context)
    stream.close
    val delimiter = " "
    Array(file.getName, handler.toString.trim).mkString(delimiter)
  }
}
```

it showing error in InputStream as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/namenode2.aibl.net:8020/ABDF/akhilaajith/PF_knnmodel_1231480046927236/visualise1/model_points/part-00000 (No such file or directory)
```

how we can  solve this issue ?

Comment: it says file not found for `hdfs:/namenode2.aibl.net:8020/ABDF/akhilaajith/PF_knnmodel_1231480046927236/visualise1/model_points/part-00000`. Maybe path is incorrect?

Comment: Path is correct . I checked that file  hdfs and have content also